# does sql 2005 database tuning advisor take into account the cost of indexes?

Tags: sql-server

Just wondering if the microsoft sql 2005 database tuning advisor takes into account the number of inserts performed on a table the the cost of adding subsequent indexes to that table?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/7/a/47a548b9-249e-484c-abd7-29f31282b04d/SQL2005DTA.doc

it does take into account the cost of updates, inserts and deletes.

Cheers!